# Using purrr to skip over errors encountered due to empty lists in data

Tags: r, purrr

I have two types of lists one populated and another unpopulated.

I can run the following code which processes and cleans the lists up for me.

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyverse)
list1 %>%
  map(., ~unlist(.x) %>% 
        data.frame() %>% 
        rownames_to_column("tag") %>% 
        setNames(c("tag", "info")) %>% # renames the columns
        pivot_wider(names_from = "tag", values_from = "info")) %>% 
  setNames(c(paste("skills", seq_along(1:length(.)), sep = "_"))) %>%  # renames the list
  bind_rows()
```

Which gives:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  name   endorsements
  <chr>  <chr>       
1 skill1 9           
2 skill2 8           
3 skill3 6           
4 skill4 5           
5 skill5 4           
6 skill6 3
```

However, some of the lists contain nothing. When I try to run the following code:

```
list2 %>%
  map(., ~unlist(.x) %>% 
        data.frame() %>% 
        rownames_to_column("tag") %>% 
        setNames(c("tag", "info")) %>% # renames the columns
        pivot_wider(names_from = "tag", values_from = "info")) %>% 
  setNames(c(paste("skills", seq_along(1:length(.)), sep = "_"))) %>%  # renames the list
  bind_rows()
```

I get this error:

> Error in names(object) <- nm :    'names' attribute [2] must be the
> same length as the vector [0]

The error comes from the line `setNames(c(paste("skills", seq_along(1:length(.)), sep = "_")))` since it is trying to rename an empty list. I have tried wrapping one of `purrr`'s `safely`, `quietly` and `possibly` functions around it without luck.

How can I "skip" over the results which return an error or have empty lists? I still want something returned, since even if the list is empty, it's list location (i.e. `list[[762]]`) corresponds to another list in a separate object located at `list[[762]]` - so removing empty lists is not a suitable option.

List 1: (populated)

```
list1 <- list(c(name = "skill1", endorsements = "9"), c(name = "skill2", 
                                                        endorsements = "8"), c(name = "skill3", 
                                                                               endorsements = "6"), c(name = "skill4", endorsements = "5"), 
              c(name = "skill5", endorsements = "4"), c(name = "skill6", 
                                                        endorsements = "3"))
```

List 2: (unpopulated)

```
list2 <- list()
```

Comment: How about an `if_else` statement in the function that checks for error/empty list and returns nothing if so?

Answer (score 2):

Change `setNames` to `vars_rename` from the `tidyselect` package, which allows you to skip missing columns by setting `strict = FALSE`.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyselect)
list2 %>%
  map(., ~unlist(.x) %>% 
        data.frame() %>% 
        rownames_to_column("tag") %>% 
        vars_rename(c("tag", "info"), strict = FALSE) %>% # renames the columns
        pivot_wider(names_from = "tag", values_from = "info"))
[1] list()
```

This will still fail at your later stage however, but this is due to how you are using `paste0` however

```
list2 %>% 
    vars_rename(c(paste('skills', seq_along(.), sep = '_')), strict = FALSE)
```

> Error: `vars` must be a character vector
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

The problem is simply that `paste('skills', seq_along(.), sep = '_')` will return `list()` to `vars_rename` which requires the first input to be a character vector. Some error handling seems to be in order, or simply testing if partial result is an empty list.